# Best way to start multiple dependent spring boot microservices locally?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices, spring-cloud

Currently my team maintains many spring boot microservices. When running them locally, our workflow is to open a new IntelliJ IDEA window and pressing the "run" button for each microservice. This does the same thing as typing `gradle bootRun`. At a minimum each service depends on a config server (from which they get their config settings) and a eureka server. Their dependencies are specified in a bootstrap.yml file. I was wondering if there is a way to just launch one microservice (or some script or run configuration), and it would programatically know which dependencies to start along with the service I am testing? It seems cumbersome to start them the way we do now.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using docker then you could use docker compose to launch services in a specific order using the `depends_on` option. Take a look here and see if that will solve your problem.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: I am not using docker, they are just plain old spring apps. Also I cannot move to docker. That would do the job if I was, though.

Comment: You can use docker just for local development without altering how you deploy your apps.